# Legacy Layers (now Collections) in older project are grayed out (invisible)?

Tags: interface, collections

I'm reacquainting myself with Blender after a hiatus of several years. I see that Blender 2.93.5 now has Collections instead of Layers. I've opened this legacy file where the Layers are now Collections. **Problem is that all but one of the Collections is grayed out--and invisible. How do I make the grayed out Collections visible?** I've researched this and nothing I've tried works. Any suggestions? Thanks. Windows 10 Blender 2.93.5

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This might not work so I won't add it as an answer yet, but it's worth a try: Above the list of collections, there's a filter drop down (looks like a funnel). Try clicking the Selectable icon (second from the left) which will add a selectable icon to each collection and object and see if the invisible ones are disabled. If they are you can drag the mouse right down the list of selectable icons to enable all of them at once and then do the same with the viewport visibility (eye) icons to hopefully make everything visible.

Comment: John Eason, thank you for your suggestion. That worked! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Glad to help! The question has been closed now so I'll just leave my comment there.